# Adobe Clip's features in Adobe Premiere

Tags: premiere

Adobe has made mobile [application](http://www.adobe.com/products/premiere-clip.html) called Adobe Clip. It can automatically cut videos, zoom stills and sync them with background music.

Can I do something similar in full-fledged Premiere? I want something that can automatically trim and sync with music for me.

I know, that clip from mobile app can be later imported to full-fledged Premiere, but to do that I need to transfer my videos to Android device, edit in the app, and later transfer it back to PC. I'd prefer to do all of this quickly and on just one machine.

Answer (score 1):

To my knowledge, there's not a comparable feature in Premiere Pro. That sort of "automatic" feature is one more often found in basic/entry-level editors, like the mobile Clip or iMovie. My guess is that this type of feature isn't included in more advanced editors for a couple reasons:

- Typically, if you're working in something as advanced as Premiere, you'll want full control over your synchronization with background music. You'd rather do it yourself than have the machine do it for you.
- Editors using NLEs like Premiere would rather have more advanced customization and other features than have the software developers spend time adding automation to things (like creating slideshows) that they, as editors, feel they could do better on their own anyway.

Just my take on it. From my experience, if I was making a slideshow requiring zooming/panning of stills, I'd much rather do it manually than let a machine do it. I feel like I can too easily spot an automatically generated slideshow (heads cut off on pans/zooms, etc.).